# Type 'File[] | { [fieldname: string]: File[]; }' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: node.js, typescript, express.js, multer, cdn

Meu código:

```
const urls = [];
const files = request.files!;
for (const file of files) {
  const { path: images } = file;
  const cdn = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(images, {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    crop: 'fill'
  });
  urls.push(cdn.secure_url);
}
```

screenshot: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei com o **forEach** e o **map** e acabei não gostando tanto do resultado, utilizando o **for** funciona mas entretanto tenho este problema que tento sem sucesso resolver por conta própria o que me impede de buildar a aplicação sem erros.

Alguém tem uma solução ou uma ideia mais elegante para resolver-se questões como essas?

Uma das vária tentativas que fiz foi adicionar no **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"
    ]
  }
}
```

mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Tente trocar o **of** por **in**. `for (const file in files) { ... }`

Comment: @JonathanSilva Seguindo a tua recomendação, na linha onde temos `const {path: image} = file` retorna este erro: **Property 'path' does not exist on type 'String'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de mais alguns testes verificou-se que na expressão `const files = request.files` a constante **files** não era reconhecida com um **Array**, logo, quando passava `for (file of files)` no **files** dava o erro para retornar um **iterator**.

A solução foi me certificar de que a constante **files** chegasse de fato com um **Array**, ficando a expressão desta forma:

```
const urls: string[] = [];
const files = request.files as [];
for (const file of files) {
  const { path: images } = file;
  const cdn = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(images, {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    crop: 'fill'
  });
  urls.push(cdn.secure_url);
}
```

Podemos aplicar a mesma solução utilizando o `forEach`:

```
const urls: string[] = [];
const files = request.files as [];
files.forEach( async (file) => {
  const { path: images } = file;
  const cdn = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(images, {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    crop: 'fill',
    folder: 'skylab',
  });
  urls.push(cdn.secure_url);
}
```

Qual das soluções devemos utilizar? Depende do contexto, sabendo a diferença entre `for` e `forEach` fica muito mais fácil decidir a melhor solução para o seu caso.

Se não souber a diferença entre os dois, penso que as respostas que encontrará no link abaixo poderão ajudar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929586/what-is-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach